# CSS fill parent width

Tags: css, sass, vue.js

I'm struggling to set the div width to the remaining width of the container div. In the example below I want the red div (an `input`) to take as much space as possible. If you enter anything in the `input` the green div appears, which should always be right aligned.

<s>I don't want to use either `flex` nor `display: table-*` or workarounds like setting `overflow: hidden` for to make space for floats.</s>

**EDIT:** I'm looking for **any** solution that works for **IE10+** (including `display: table-*`, etc.)

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/23xo3wjjrp (Change the `template` and `style` tag inside `/components/SearchBox.vue` for changes)

The example uses `vue`, but for completeness I post the code here too:

HTML

```
<div class="ms-Fabric ms-SearchBox" :class="searchBoxStyle">

  <div class="ms-SearchBox-iconContainer">
    <i class="ms-SearchBox-icon ms-Icon ms-Icon--Search"></i>
  </div>
  <input class="ms-SearchBox-field" type="text" placeholder="Search"      
         v-model="searchQuery" ref="input"
         @blur="onBlur" @focus="onFocus">
  <div class="ms-SearchBox-clearButton" v-show="searchQuery.length > 0"
       @click="clear">
    <i class="ms-SearchBox-icon ms-Icon ms-Icon--Clear"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
// Active styles
.ms-SearchBox.is-active {
  .ms-SearchBox-iconContainer {
    width: 4px;
    transition: width .167s;
    .ms-SearchBox-icon {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}

// Static styles
.ms-SearchBox {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
  height: 32px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  width: 208px;

  .ms-SearchBox-iconContainer {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #106ebe;
    transition: width .167s;
    .ms-SearchBox-icon {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity .167s 0s;
    }
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  .ms-SearchBox-field {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 32px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }


  .ms-SearchBox-iconContainer,
  .ms-SearchBox-clearButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .ms-SearchBox-clearButton {
    font-size: 14px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);

    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add code *here*. So that when future users of SO come to this question, they can see the code you're referring to as your sandbox won't be live forever.

Comment: Why not just use flex? You don't want to use flex, or float, or table or... well anything that will let you do what you want.

Comment: I want to support IE9+, that's why. I think I'll use `width: calc(100% - ...)` to fill the container.

Comment: @Johannes `calc` is not as reliable as `display:table`; e.g. it makes IE9 crash under some circumstances, according to caniuse.

Comment: Use `position:absolute, top:0; bottom:0;` inside a `position:relative` container.

Comment: @MrLister as per `caniuse`, this crash only occurs if used inside `background-position`.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to set a `width:100%` to your `input`, and to set `position:absolute` to your icon containers. With paddings on the input, this should do the thing.

Hope I understood the question :)